# Text To Speech from an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, text-to-speech

I made a list of animals in 2 language and how to pronounce it. 
But when I click the speech button it only say the first word from the array list (which is "Swan") how do I make it say the next word? I'm lost and new to Android Studio :(

[image]

how should I finish the 'position' methods?

```
public class ListHewan extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    ImageButton speakButton;
    TextView speakText;

    int[] images = {R.drawable.angsa,
            R.drawable.anjing};

    String[] indo = {"Indonesia: Angsa",
            "Indonesia: Anjing"};

    String[] english = {"Swan",
            "Dog"

    };


    ListView mListView;
    public int position;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_hewan);

        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                } else {
                    speakButton.setEnabled(true);
                    speak();
                }
            }
        });

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List_Hewan);
        speakText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.englishView);

        CustomAdaptor customAdaptor = new CustomAdaptor();
        mListView.setAdapter(customAdaptor);
    }



    private void speak() {
        String text = english[position].toString();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
        else
            textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

    }


    class CustomAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customlayout, null);
            ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.hewanView);
            TextView mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.indoView);
            TextView nTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.englishView);
            ImageButton mButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.Spkbutton);

            mImageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
            mTextView.setText(indo[position]);
            nTextView.setText(english[position]);

            mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    speak();
                }
            });

            return view;
        }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (textToSpeech != null) {
            textToSpeech.stop();
            textToSpeech.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: The point is: all that code you are showing only "receives" a position argument. Obviously, that argument is always 0. So you probably have to make sure that some methods are also called for other values of position ...

Comment: @GhostCat alright, let me find a way to make that! Thankyou~

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I just need to add this

```
  private void speak(int pos) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                textToSpeech.speak(english[pos],TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,null);
            else
                textToSpeech.speak(english[pos],TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
```

Thanks for those who have tried to help!

Answer (score -1):

You could do as -

```
ArrayList<String> english = new ArrayList<String>();
english.add("Swan");
english.add("Dog");
tts.speak(english, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

It will speak all the words from ArrayList english.

Comment: it still only mention the first from array D: